# Counting permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, algorithms, permutation-matrices

$J \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ is a matrix with all elements being $1$. $S := \{P_1, P_2, ..., P_n\}$ is a set with $n$ permutation matrices $P_i \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n P_i = J$. Please count the number of $S$ with respect to $n$ (denoted as $C(n)$).

$\textbf{Motivation & Background:} $

The motivation of this problem comes from a naive geometry problem. Given a $n \times n \times n$ Rubik's cube $M$ with $n^3$ cubes. How many ways are there to pick $n^2$ cubes $M^{'} \subset M$ such that $M^{'}$ have the same orthographic views (front view, end view, and vertical view) with $M$, i.e., all orthographic views of $M$ have to be $n \times n$ squares? I define $n$ layers from top to bottom, each layer of $M^{'}$ is a permutation matrix so that front/end views of $M^{'}$ are square. To make the vertical view a square, the sum of the permutation matrices has to be an all-one matrix ($J$).

$\textbf{Attempts:}$

1. Consider special values. For $n=1,2,3,4$, the corresponding $C(n)$ are $1, 1, 2, 24$. But I do not know the exact numbers for $n>4$.
2. Let the group $S_n$ act on the set of $S$, i.e., a set with such $S$ being its elements. But not successful yet.

Note: The geometry problem comes from a math contest (5th grade in the primary school) of my younger brother for a trivial case $n=4$ (correct answer: $576$). I find the closed-form of $C(n)$ might be non-trivial. It is even very hard to solve it with C++ as the complexity is exponential. I am working on an efficient algorithm (better parallel, multithreading) to compute $C(n)$. Answers are still welcome (100 bounties for highly insightful answers).

Comment: For example, in the 2D ($n=2$) case, there is only one $S = \{\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right]\}$

Comment: For the 3D case, there are $3!=6$ choices of $P_1$. When $P_1$ is fixed, there are $2$ choices $P_2$. We have $12$ choices of $P_1, P_2,P_3$, modulo the permutation of $P_1, P_2, P_3$ we have 2 choices of $S$.

Comment: For the 4D case, there are $4!=24$ choices of $P_1$, $6$ choices of $P_2$ and $4$ choices of $P_3$. So there are $\frac{24*6*4}{4!} = 24$ choices of $S$.

Comment: If you take $\sum kP_k$ you have a [Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square). As you can permute the coefficients, you have to take the number of $n\times n$ latin squares and divide it by $n!$. The article about latin squares says that there is no easy formula for the number of $n\times n$ latin squares. It is sequence [A002860](https://oeis.org/A002860) in the OEIS.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier that's very elegant. Divided by the $n!$ it is sequence [A000479](https://oeis.org/A000479) in the OEIS.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Good idea to construct a bijection of this problem to the Latin square! The idea is an excellent application of generating functions. The difficulty of this 5th-grade problem is incredible for me.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thanks for your source! I am not very familiar with the Latin square. The bijection between this problem and the Latin square has not occurred to me.